# Admin cache only showing refresh in dropdown

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis, magento2.2.3

I've **disabled** and **enabled** and **cleared** and **flushed** cache through

```
php bin/magento cahce:disable
php bin/magento cahce:enable
php bin/magento cahce:clean
php bin/magento cahce:flush
```

Recently i just noticed i turned the **cache** on and then in **admin** it's showing that they are all **disabled** still.

Also, after selecting actions there is only refresh too in the drop down.

[image]

It's not a big deal because i can cross reference the DB to make sure they are turned on as well as using **cmd** line but it's kind of bugging me that they are still red and i can't use the **admin** caching panel.

**EE 2.2.3**

Any ideas?

[image]

Maybe i didn't setup my env.php file correctly? Is there anything that stands out to you as wrong?

```
<?php
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
  'db' => 
  array (
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'indexer' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => '2_EE',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'active' => '1',
        'persistent' => NULL,
      ),
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => '2_EE',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'host',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
  ),
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => 'b****',
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
  ),
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
  'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => 
    array (
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '6379',
      'password' => '',
      'timeout' => '2.5',
      'persistent_identifier' => '',
      'database' => '2',
      'compression_threshold' => '2048',
      'compression_library' => 'gzip',
      'log_level' => '7',
      'max_concurrency' => '6',
      'break_after_frontend' => '5',
      'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
      'first_lifetime' => '600',
      'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
      'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
      'disable_locking' => '0',
      'min_lifetime' => '60',
      'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
    ),
  ),
  'cache' => 
  array (
    'frontend' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'database' => '0',
          'port' => '6379',
        ),
      ),
      'page_cache' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => '6379',
          'database' => '1',
          'compress_data' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'target_rule' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
  ),
  'install' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Fri, 02 Mar 2018 18:06:06 +0000',
  ),
  'system' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'dev' => 
      array (
        'debug' => 
        array (
          'debug_logging' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I have redis installed and i've used `redis-cli flushall` as well.

I've installed two modules today and when i check to see if they are installed on command line `bin/magento modules:status` I see that they are there and installed but they as well are not appearing on the backend.

Comment: Are there any other cache backend mechanisms at play besides default files? Judging from the bookmarks/tabs possibly memcache or redis? Also if Varnish is in place in front of your web server it could be cached there as well. If redis https://github.com/erikdubbelboer/phpRedisAdmin and an easy one-liner for memcache: `watch 'php -r '"'"'$m=new Memcache;$m->connect("127.0.0.1", 11211);print_r($m->getstats());'"'"`

Comment: Yes, I just installed redis but i feel like it was happening before that too. Although, I'm not really sure; I'll just go with it started happening after installing redis since you mentioned that could be why. I like the redis admin module. I may install that module. Thank you

Comment: @B00MER I notice other things are missing as well. ie.  Stores > Configuration > Advanced... I only have Admin and System.. no Developer tab... see image above.

Comment: Judging from the screenshot, disabling some of the 3rd party modules may help identify the culprit, as out-of-box Magento 2.2.x should function properly. Most likely as you notice the missing developer setting is related to your caching issue. BTW, I censored your crypt key just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks @B00MER, I've only installed 3 modules total and the first one was B2B. It was happening before i installed the two new 3rd party modules yesterday.

Comment: Is there any JS errors or in HTML around the areas in question on the cache grid admin page? Also in developer mode and if so, is there any relevant details in `var/log/` that may shed more light on a cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an answer to this question but what I ended up doing was just reinstalling and starting over. I guess we can just mark this as closed.